# Excel formula checking multiple conditions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a grading sheet for my students in excel, but I am stuck on a complex formula. I am trying to create a formula that will do this:

```
If(Cells A1 AND B1 AND C1 >= 24)AND(Cells D1 AND E1 AND F1 AND G1 AND H1 >=120 and <174)
Then Print "Level 2 PP"
Else IF (Cells A1 AND B1 AND C1 >= 24)AND(Cells D1 AND E1 AND F1 AND G1 AND H1 >=150 and <204)
Then Print "Level 2 MP"
Else If(Cells A1 AND B1 AND C1 < 24)AND(Cells D1 AND E1 AND F1 AND G1 AND H1 >=120 and <174)
Then Print "Level 1 Pass"
```

I hope this gives an idea of what I am trying to achieve. It's very hard to understand as the students have to achieve a certain amount of points in certain units to achieve certain grades. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No we cannot guess. Tell us your rule then we can say if anything wrong in your formula or will suggest new solution.

Comment: generally speaking, there's no (useful) programming languages where you can do a multi-comparison using `(a and b and c) != foo` and have it work the way you think it should work.

Comment: This is what I got so far, but no luck as of yet =IF(AND(SUM(DU7:DW7)>24,DR7>144),"Level 2 PP", OR(IF(AND(SUM(DU7:DW7)>24, DR7>174), "Level 2 MP")))

Comment: What about all the ranges of values you have not included? For instace A1=24, B1=24, C1 = 25, D1=121, E1 = 1140, F1 = 150, G1 = 160, H1 = 175). Non of your conditions apply to that (as an example of very, very many)

Comment: Those ranges are used for other data thats unrelated to what I am trying to achieve. The ranges I am checking is from cells DU to EB

Comment: Just to understand, for example, in your first statement, are you saying you want `A1 >=24, B2 >= 24 and C1 >=24` OR `(A1+B1+C1) >= 24`? - Similar question for D thru H...

Comment: I have done it like this IF(AND(SUM(DU7:DW7)>24,DR7>144). So essentially like (A1+B1+C1) >= 24?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the way to do what you want to accomplish is with Nested If statements.

Before getting to that, the conditions you list in your question could be constructed like this:

1. `IF(AND(MIN(A1:C1)>=24,MIN(D1:H1)>=120,MAX(D1:H1)<174),"Level 2 PP",
       "Not Level 2 PP")`
2. `IF(AND(MIN(A1:C1)>=24,MIN(D1:H1)>=150,MAX(D1:H1)<204),"Level 2
       MP","Not Level 2 MP")`
3. `IF(AND(MIN(A1:C1)<24,MIN(D1:H1)>=120,MAX(D1:H1)<174),"Level 1
       Pass","Not Level 1 Pass")`

Putting these together, I get:

```
=IF(AND(MIN(A1:C1)>=24,MIN(D1:H1)>=150,MAX(D1:H1)<204),"Level 2
MP",IF(AND(MIN(A1:C1)>=24,MIN(D1:H1)>=120,MAX(D1:H1)<174),"Level 2 
PP",IF(AND(MIN(A1:C1)<24,MIN(D1:H1)>=120,MAX(D1:H1)<174),"Level 1 
Pass","Other")))
```

The criteria for "Level 2 MP" overlaps with "Level 2 PP." I made the "Level 2 MP" the "outside of the nest," so, in the case of overlap, student will be identified as Level 2 MP.

I strongly suspect the categories you are interested in aren't exactly as you described them. For one thing, as noted above, they overlap.  And, assuming a bigger number is better, does a student really not "Level 1 pass" if one of A1, B1 or C1 are > 24?

If there are more categories, or if the criteria are more complicated, I'd consider using separate columns to do some of the intermediate calculations.  Hope this helps.